# insert data to Berkeley DB very poor performance in Big Data

Tags: performance, berkeley-db

I have already held the 80G Berkeley DB file. I measure the average insert speed is 8ms for one record(32 byte key/100 byte value) without transaction.

Compare to insert to empty database with same interface, the average speed is 3~6 us.

Comment: Was there a question in there?

Comment: I things it is too slow for key_value database. Is this performance normal value? I was wondering if there's something I missed that can improve my speeds?

Answer (score 0):

If you insert data when your buffers are empty it can perform every well, once the buffers of your system are full, they cannot continue until some buffer space has been clearer. e.g. the time to write data to a HDD is typically 8 ms.

I would test busts of say one million records, after the system is quiet to see what the latency is like when the buffers are not full.

Comment: Thanks Peter, I am sure the buffers is empty because i have test the speed at the beginning of starting.

Comment: In thank case, I suggest is parititoning the data. You shouldn't need to IMHO but it may be your only option.